# Shell Script - run for random number of times in the range

Tags: linux, shell-script, xdotool

I am trying to automate a shell script that use Xdotol (press B key with random interval -sec.milsec).

I am unable to to run script random number of times (right now it is limited to 25 times by count).
I am looking for a way o get random number for a count (in range 20-45) or any other idea how can I get random number of time a loop iterates.

Batch 1 - 25 times B key + random sleep 
Batch 2 - 20 times B key + random sleep 
Batch 3 - 35 times B key + random sleep 
Batch 4 - 45 times B key + random sleep 
....

Thank You for any help.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
 xdotool key b
    sleep $((1 + RANDOM %1)).$((RANDOM%999))

    count=$(( $count+1 ))
 if [ "$count" = "25" ]; then
        count=0
    sleep $((1 + RANDOM % 1)).$((RANDOM%99))
    echo " blah"
 fi

done
```

---

**Updated with comment from user Bodo**

Working code (removed decimal from sleep)

```
#!/bin/bash
max=$((20 + RANDOM % 26))
while true; do
    xdotool key b
    sleep $((0 + RANDOM %1))

    count=$(( $count+1 ))
    if [ "$count" = "$max" ]; then
        count=0
        max=$((20 + RANDOM % 26))
        sleep $((1 + RANDOM % 1))
        echo " blah"
    fi
done
```

Comment: What's wrong with your script? Describe and share error, any details

Comment: I am unable to change count to random, not fixed number. Right now it is 25, I want to get a range of 20-45 each times script runs

Comment: Edit you original post with all the needed informations...

Comment: maybe `max=$((20 + RANDOM % 26))` once and in the loop `if [ "$count" = "$max" ]`?

Comment: It ignores count number after 1-2 iterations (updated org post with code after update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `shuf` to generate n random numbers from low to high and call a function for your loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

myloop () {
    local count
    for ((count=1;count<="${1:-0}";count++)); do
        xdotool key b
        sleep $((RANDOM %2)).$((RANDOM%10))$((RANDOM%10))$((RANDOM%10))
    done
}

# run 4 times with random values between 20 and 45
for i in $(shuf -n 4 -i 20-45); do
    myloop "$i"
done

# run 4 times with random values between 20 and 45 in increments of 5
for i in $(shuf -n 4 -i 1-5); do
    myloop "$((i * 5 + 20))"
done

# run forever with random values between 20 and 45 in increments of 5
while true; do
    myloop "$(( $(shuf -n 1 -i 1-5) * 5 + 20))"
done
```

The first part of your random sleep `$((1 + RANDOM %1))` always produces 1.
The second part `$((RANDOM%999))` generates a value between 0 and 998.

I changed it to `$((RANDOM %2)).$((RANDOM%10))$((RANDOM%10))$((RANDOM%10))` to generate values between 0 and 1.999.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable, e.g. `max` to a random number and compare with this variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
max=$((20 + RANDOM % 26))
while true; do
    xdotool key b
    sleep $((1 + RANDOM %1)).$((RANDOM%999))

    count=$(( $count+1 ))
    if [ "$count" = "$max" ]; then
        count=0
        max=$((20 + RANDOM % 26))
        sleep $((1 + RANDOM % 1)).$((RANDOM%99))
        echo " blah"
    fi
done
```

Note that `sleep` does not supports integer numbers only. I did not fix this error.

Another option would be to use two nested loops.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    count=$((20 + RANDOM % 26))
    while [ "$count" -gt 0 ]; do
        xdotool key b
        sleep $((1 + RANDOM %1)).$((RANDOM%999))
        count=$(( $count-1 ))
    done
    sleep $((1 + RANDOM % 1)).$((RANDOM%99))
    echo " blah"
done
```

Comment: Looks that sleep decimal was the problem - Thank You for pointing this out. sleep $((1 + RANDOM %1)).$((RANDOM%999)) changed to sleep $((1 + RANDOM %1))